# Java desktop client nodejs server using socketio, socket not connected

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io, connection, crud

So i have a javafx application , who i use for CRUD of client, on mode "connected" i need to send data on the server, offline , i register the data in a JSONfile

When i use the controller ClientSocket (there is the run button that you can press), it shows that socket is connected , but when i launch the same code in the controller Controller (CRUD) the socket is not connected , no response from the node server

Node.JS

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io') (server)
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const apiRouter = require('./router').router
const port = 7777
const path = require('path')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  /*res.send('Hello Team7!!')*/
  res.sendFile('index.html',{ root : path.join(__dirname, '/')})
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use('/api/', apiRouter)

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.emit('hello','hello world')

  socket.on("hello", (arg,arg1,arg2) => {
    console.log(arg)
    console.log(arg1)
    console.log(arg2)
  })

  socket.on("essai_connect", (socket) => {
        console.log("user is really connected")
  })
})
```

ClientSocket (Where the socket connection work, ie java client is launched)

```
public class ClientSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:7777");
        IO.Options options = new IO.Options().builder().build();
        Socket socket = IO.socket(uri,options);
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                System.out.println("socket connected");
                System.out.println(socket.connected());
                socket.emit("hello",1,"2","Jo");
            }
        });
        socket.open();
}
```

Controller (CRUD) where the socket client doesn't lauch at all

```
public void insertClient(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "C:/Users/Dewei/IdeaProjects/ProjetClient/src/sample/client.json";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (nom.getText().isEmpty() || adresse.getText().isEmpty() || solde.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Entrer les données");
        }
        else
        {
            URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:7777");
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options().builder().build();
            Socket socket = IO.socket(uri,options);
            socket.on("essai_connect", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    System.out.println(socket.connected()); // true
                }
            });
            System.out.println("Socket");
            System.out.println(socket.connected());
            if (socket.connected())
            {
                socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        Integer soldeInt = Integer.parseInt(solde.getText());
                        socket.emit("ajout", "1",nom.getText(),adresse.getText(),soldeInt);
                        socket.close();
                        System.out.println(args[0]);
                        ObservableList<Client> clientList = null;
                        try {
                            clientList = ClientDao.getAllRecords();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        populateTable(clientList);
                        clean();
                    }
                });
                socket.open();
            }
            else
            {
                /*Integer soldeInt = Integer.parseInt(solde.getText());
                ClientDao.insertClient(1,nom.getText(),adresse.getText(),soldeInt);
                ObservableList<Client> clientList = ClientDao.getAllRecords();
                populateTable(clientList);
                clean();*/
            }
        }
    }
```

}}

please help guys , i am running out of ideas